# Signature verification for firmware

Tags: binary, cryptography, reverse-engineering, firmware

How can I verify if a firmware (.bin file) is signed or not , if there is a tool or script that can be used as much I understand sigcheck does not work with firmwares, any help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

A bin file is generally just a binary file. There is no such thing as a (single) standard for firmware files. Undoubtedly the file internally has structure but for us it is impossible to tell what it is. Generally a tool only works for a specific protocol.

RSA signatures themselves are the result of modular exponentiation with the public exponent. The result is then converted to a byte array that is *almost* indistinguishable from random. The size has the size of the modulus, which is the same size as the key size, in bytes. RSA may be used in various formats such as RSA with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding or RSA with PSS padding; the output however looks the same. Other signature types exist, e.g. ECDSA signatures that are completely different from RSA. They have a different (smaller) size and can be both dynamically and statically sized. ECDSA makes a lot of sense if the signature needs to be checked on resource constrained hardware.

Generally the signature is calculated as the very last step, so often the last bytes of the .bin file will be the signature. If you're lucky the signature is performed using a standard, e.g. PGP compliant signatures or CMS compliant signatures. For CMS signatures you may check if the file contains so called ASN.1 structures. These are encoded using something called BER, which can be parsed (e.g. using `openssl asn1parse -inform BER`).

So it all depends on the protocol. There is no single tool that can check if something is signed or not, the protocols are too different and signatures themselves just look like random data.